# How to change the clock color on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, clock

I'm using the *adapta nokto* theme on Xubuntu and the icons on my panel are white, but the problem arose when I switched to the binary clock. The clock dots are in blue! And that makes it very difficult to see when I have a bright wallpaper. I tried to change the color of the binary dots, but all attempts did  fail.

I'm a noob to linux, so please give me the simplest method as possible.

[image: Here is my desktop screenshot]